# Is there a clickhouse aggregate function similar to prometheus histogram_quantile?

Tags: prometheus, clickhouse

Given a histogram how could one calculate quantiles similar to Prometheus' histogram_quantile function?

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile

I see there's a handful of quantile functions for clickhouse but it's not clear to me how I can use histogram buckets with these functions.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference

Answer (score 1):

The `quantile*Weighted` functions calculate quantile(s) from a histogram (a set of value, weight pairs). For example, https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/quantiletimingweighted

Although I'm unsure about the histogram format in Prometheus, I assume you can apply `quantileTimingWeighted` to aggregate each histogram bucket.